# Google Apps Script - Add email addresses to folder share from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I have the following problem that I hope to solve through Google Apps Script:

- We want to make a Drive folder with sharing set to "OFF - only specific people can access"
- We'll have a one-column Google Sheets document that has a list of email addresses
- All email addresses in this sheet should be given `VIEW` permissions for everything in that folder.

I think I want to use `getFolderById(id)`, but I'm not entirely sure. Is this enough information? Apologies for my lack of knowledge on this.

Comment: You should use `getFolderById(id)`.  And then use the `setSharing()` method.  [Link to Apps Script Documentation - setSharing](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#setsharingaccesstype-permissiontype)  When using the documentation, always look at the return type.  The return type for `getFolderById(id)` is `folder`.  Then you can look at the folder class to see what is available for methods.  It the time it took you to write your question and post it, you could have just searched the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This skeleton code can be modified to set up a folder with the required permission settings:

```
function driveShare(){
  //Get the spreadsheet you want to access
  var ss= SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)
  // Get the sheet which holds the email to give access to? in this case name is 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Access Sheet Name here")
  // Get values from cells A1 to A50. Assuming your email address are present here
  var getEmails = sheet.getRange("A1:A50").getValues() 
  // Create a floder to be shared by default it is not shared
  var folder = DriveApp.createFolder('Shared Folder');
  // or get a folder by id
  var folder2 = DriveApp.getFolderById(id)
  for ( i in getEmails)
     folder.addViewer(getEmails[i][0])

}
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks pretty close to what I'm looking for. But when I swap out the IDs, it gives me an error: `TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 7, file "Code")`

Comment: Did you change the "Access Sheet Name here" to the name of the sheet you are trying to access?